# Devextreme-intl localization messages not found in angular 5 app

Tags: angular, localization, devextreme

I am working on localizing some devextreme components in my app. I decided to do this with devextreme-intl. I have an issue when I try to import messages.
I wrote this:

```
import deMessages from 'devextreme/localization/messages/de.json';
```

but I get an error: Cannot find module 'devextreme/localization/messages/de.json'. I checked and this file exists in node modules, so I don't know what the issue is. 
I am trying to achieve something like this:
https://js.devexpress.com/Demos/WidgetsGallery/Demo/Localization/UsingIntl/Angular/Light/

Answer (score 4):

**Using Wildcard Module Name**

In your TS Definition file, e.g. `typings.d.ts`, you can add this line:

`declare module "*.json" {
    const value: any;
    export default value;
}`

source : https://hackernoon.com/import-json-into-typescript-8d465beded79

Answer (score 2):

At first, add this to `typings.d.ts`:

```
declare module "*.json" {
    const value: any;
    export default value;
}
```

Then, import the whole json file into a string like this:

```
import * as deMessages from 'devextreme/localization/messages/de.json';
```

Answer (score 2):

Since TyeScript 2.9 you can do:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true  
  }
}
```

(https://hackernoon.com/import-json-into-typescript-8d465beded79)